# $scope.$watch on an array is not updating when the values are added from a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm sure this is just a newbie mistake... here's the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/L5702XAtQwBRmzP2kqoA?p=preview

I have a directive which updates a value based on a selected checkbox:

```
// --- 8< ---
// Detect click on checkbox, get value, etc... then:
// --- 8< ---
scope.$apply(function() {
    if ($this.prop("checked")) {
        selected.push(value);
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < selected.length; i++) {
            if (selected[i] == value) {
                selected.splice(i, 1);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    console.log("selected updated to: " + selected)
});
```

I'm watching that collection back in the page's controller:

```
$scope.$watch("model.selected", function(selected) {
    console.log("----- Controller updated with: ", selected);
});
```

The `console.log` statement here only shows once, when the page first loads. However, on the page, I've got a binding which shows the selected values array:

```
Selected: {{ model.selected }}
```

This *does* get updated.

Why doesn't my watch get updated, too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be notified when a collection (ie. array) has values added, removed, changed you need to use the 
$scope.$watchCollection method.

Change this:

```
$scope.$watch("model.selected", function(selected) {
    console.log("----- Controller updated with: ", selected);
});
```

to this:

```
$scope.$watchCollection("model.selected", function(selected) {
    console.log("----- Controller updated with: ", selected);
});
```

Here is the updated plunkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/f2xCge2ragh5uWKRRwof?p=preview

Comment: Well I was right on one thing - it was a rookie mistake. I hadn't even heard of `watchCollection` before. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

if you only need to monitor the length changes then use

```
$scope.$watch("model.selected.length", function() {
    console.log("----- Controller updated with: ", $scope.model.selected);
});
```

NB: watching only length will be much faster operation.

Comment: Great suggestion, I have to admit I didn't think of that! In this case though, I *do* need to watch what changes in the array (this was just a simplified example) - but thanks for pointing it out.